# Dozer not converting Map with proper key and null/blank value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dozer

I am using Dozer for VO conversion and here is the mapping details:

```
<mapping wildcard="false" map-null="true" map-empty-string="true" map-id="Map_ServiceInstanceBasicDetailVO_Mapping">
        <class-a>java.util.Map</class-a>
        <class-b>com.XXX.customer.valueobject.ServiceInstanceBasicDetailVO</class-b>
        <field>
            <a key="DUNNINGEXCLUSION">this</a>
            <b  set-method="setDunnigExcludeCustom">dunningExcluded</b>
        </field>
    </mapping>
```

Here, I am trying to set value of dunningExcluded from the HashMap using Key "DUNNINGEXCLUSION" using dozer mapping but it does not calling the method "setDunnigExcludeCustom" while the conversion. Am I missing something in the mapping configuration. Thanks in advance.

setDunningExcludeCustom method code snippet:

```
package com.xxx.customer.valueobject;

import com.xxx.core.constants.CommonConstant;
import com.xxx.core.util.CommonFunctionUtils;

public class ServiceInstanceBasicDetailVO {

    private String dunningExcluded;

    /* other fields' getter setter and declaration*/

    public void setDunnigExcludeCustom(String dunningExclude){

        String dunningStatus;
        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(dunningExclude)){
            dunningStatus = CommonConstant.N_CONSTANT;
        }else{
            dunningStatus = dunningExclude;
        }
        setDunningExcluded(dunningStatus);
    }
}
```

Comment: is the setDunnigExcludeCustom method in a CustomConverter or a normal bean class? Could you show us that as well?

Comment: Its a normal method of POJO class.